# anonymous lambda?

Tags: c#

What is the closest thing to the below? Unfortunately the below gets me a method name compile error.

```
int val = delegate(string s)
{
    return 1;
}("test");
```

I also tried the (...)=>{...} syntax but got it very wrong

Comment: C# is not javascript, you know?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both forms of anonymous function (lambda expressions and anonymous methods) require a specific type to convert to. So this is valid:

```
int val = ((Func<string, int>)(delegate(string s)
{
    return 1;
}))("test");
```

And so is this:

```
int val = ((Func<string, int>)(s => 1))("test");
```

I wouldn't actually suggest *using* either of them though. It's much more readable to use a separate local variable:

```
Func<string, int> del = s => 1;
int val = del("test");
```

(You can use constructor-like syntax as well, as per yBee's answer - but I personally prefer the cast style syntax.)

Comment: Awesome. And if you need more than 1 line to resolve the return, the syntax would be: `Func<string, int> del = (s) => { return 1; };`.

Comment: I any day prefer `new Func.. (lambda)(...)` than `((Func...)(lambda))(...)` :)

Answer (score 5):

```
new Func<string, int>(s => 1)("test")
```

Answer (score 4):

The following would compile:

```
int val = ((Func<string, int>)(s => 1))("test");
```

But that doesn't look very useful to me.